# Exposing 3rd party library through own library?

Tags: c#

I have the following dependency structure:

`ProjectA -> ProjectB -> Dapper`

I want to allow `ProjectA` to have access to Dapper's functionalities. Is it possible to do it with `ProjectB` "exposing Dapper" to `ProjectA`, instead of independently adding Dapper to `ProjectA` via nuget?

Comment: [Facade pattern](http://www.dofactory.com/net/facade-design-pattern).

Answer (score 1):

You can either wrap what you need and expose your own abstractions, so that project a does not even need to know that dapper exists, or just reference the package in both libraries.

If you're not trying to achieve anything in particular, like abstraction of the specific implementation, just reference it from both.